# Етимологія терміну "інклюзивність"

Tags: етимологія, запозичені-слова, іншомовні-слова

Останнім часом в українському суспільстві набуває розголошення тема "*інклюзивності*" у [навчанні](https://mon.gov.ua/ua/tag/inklyuzivne-navchannya) (освіті), житті, послугах і навіть [політиці](https://www.pravda.com.ua/columns/2014/04/19/7023016/).
Стало цікаво, а звідки цей термін до нас прийшов? Також цікавили його значення та доречність вживання.

Вікіпедія [надає](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%8F) наступне пояснення:

> **Інклюзія** (від англ. inclusion — включення) — процес збільшення ступеня участі всіх громадян в соціумі. І насамперед тих, що мають труднощі у фізичному чи розумовому розвитку. Він передбачає розробку і застосування таких конкретних рішень, які зможуть дозволити кожній людині рівноправно брати участь в академічному і суспільному житті. Поняття інклюзії близьке за значенням з поняттям інтеграція та протилежне до сегрегація. При інклюзії всі зацікавлені сторони повинні брати активну участь для отримання бажаного результату.
>
> Інклюзія в широкому соціально-філософському сенсі розуміється як форма буття, спільного життя звичайних людей і людей з обмеженими можливостями (інвалідів), за чи проти якої виступає суспільство та його підсистеми (у тому числі інститути освіти), і по відношенню до якої і ті, й інші члени суспільства мають право вільного вибору.
>
> Інклюзія — це процес реального включення осіб з інвалідністю в активне суспільне життя і однаковою мірою необхідна для всіх членів суспільства. Інвалідність — це не вирок долі, це, швидше, такий спосіб життя за обставин, що склалися, який може багато дати особі з інвалідністю і людям, що оточують її, якщо інвалідність розглядати в рамках соціальної концепції. Тоді головний сенс процесу інклюзії можна позначити так: «Всім тут раді!» Або може стати нестерпним щоденним стражданням для всіх членів суспільства, якщо інвалідність розглядати тільки в рамках біологічної концепції, коли «Інвалід — людина, яка повністю або частково позбавлена працездатності унаслідок якої-небудь аномалії, поранення, каліцтва, хвороби» (С.І. Ожегов).

[Вікісловник](https://uk.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&title=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA&profile=default&fulltext=1&searchToken=unx1qxavs7qrfcuu0hbl1g45), [Офіційний сайт Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&t=0), щодо "*інклюзивності*"  відповідей не дають.
Пошуки в інших джерелах результату або не дали, чи мають мінімальне, або вже зазначене пояснення.

Отже, хотілось би знати, звідки та коли цей термін до нас прийшов, його більш ширші значення (крім вже наведених) та історія походження.

Comment: мені здається, чи в найпершому реченні щось не так з синтаксисом?

Comment: Перепрошую, але це має відношення до розгляду питання "Етимологія терміну “інклюзивність"?

Comment: я саме пишу відповідь, а окремо написав комент, щоби питання стало зрозумілішим. ми тут цінуємо якість як відповідей, так і запитань, як змісту, так і форми.

Comment: Тобто, що запитати, треба мати науковий ступінь з лінгвистики чи хоча б ступінь кандидата? Правильно я Вас зрозумів? Чи звичайні пересічні користувачі ресурсу теж мають право висловлювати свої думки у доступній та притаманній їм формі?

Comment: ні, ви неправильно мене зрозуміли. мені просто складно розуміти перше речення. може, там просто замість слова "щодо" треба поставити слово "тема"?

Comment: я поредаґував трохи, подивіться, чи не викривив того, що ви намагалися донести?

Comment: Гадаю нічого страшного від зміни "щодо" на "тема" не сталося, але на мою скоромну думку, сполучення "щодо інклюзивності" теж непогано звучало і мало певну стилістичну форму.

Comment: але що там набувало розголошення щодо інклюзивності? там не було підмета.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77799/discussion-between-p-vovk-and-m0rpheus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шукаю [інклюзивність у корпусі української мови](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/view?q=q%5Blc%3D%22%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22%20%7C%20lemma_lc%3D%22%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22%5D;fromp=1;corpname=grac&attrs=word&ctxattrs=word&structs=&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.original%2C%3Ddoc.genre%2C%3Ddoc.region%2C%3Ddoc.translator&pagesize=30&iquery=%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C;navpos=next2), звідти висновую, що цей термін прийшов до нас з західного дискурсу. На підтвердження коротко аналізую основні джерела:

1. "Нічого для нас без нас. Посібник з інклюзивного прийняття рішень для державних органів" (2015) виданий **за фінансової підтримки Європейської Комісії та Британської Ради.**
2. Ярослава Бедрич. "Категорія інклюзивності у мові науки: функціонально-когнітивні та дискурсивні характеристики (на матеріалі **англо-американських** статей у галузі інформаційно-комунікаційних технологій)". 2017.
3. Дарон Аджемоґлу, Джеймс Робінсон. "Чому нації занепадають" (2016) - книга від **британських** економістів.

Розібралися, що термін цей не так давно зайшов в українську мову, хоч тепер його вже й використовують повсюдно (у Майкла Щура в «#@)₴?$0» є навіть окрема рубрика "інклюзивність"). Розібралися, здається і з походженням. Перейдемо до етимолоґії, яку тепер можемо шукати [англійською](https://www.etymonline.com/word/inclusion):

> **inclusion** (n.) c. 1600, "act of making a part of," from Latin
>   inclusionem (nominative inclusio) "a shutting up, confinement," noun
>   of action from past participle stem of includere (see include).
>   Meaning "that which is included" is from 1839.

Перекладаю українською:

> **інклюзія** (іменник), приблизно від 1600 року, "дія за значенням робити частиною чогось", від латинського inclusionem (називний відмінок inclusio) "закриття, ув'язнення", іменник дії від кореня минулого часу includere (див. include). Значення "той, що його включили" виникло у 1839 році.

*(переклад уточнюватиму)*

Також впадає в око велика концентрація українського розуміння інклюзії на "людях з інвалідністю", а не загалом на людях, які не мають повного доступу до всіх сфер життя навколо них (наприклад, батьки з немовлятами у візочках/колясках).

Наведу визначення з англійської вікіпедії:

> Social inclusion, the converse of social exclusion, is affirmative action to change the circumstances and habits that lead to (or have led to) social exclusion. The World Bank defines social inclusion as the process of improving the ability, opportunity, and dignity of people, disadvantaged on the basis of their identity, to take part in society.

Переклад українською:

> Соціальна інклюзія, антонім соціальної ексклюзії, це позитивна дія, спрямована на зміну обставин і звичок, які призводять до соціальної ексклюзії *(ізоляції, відокремлення)*. Світовий Банк визначає соціальну інклюзію так: це процес поліпшення спроможностей і гідності людей, що мають певні обмеження через свою ідентичність, надання їм можливості брати участь у житті суспільства.